# How to get my fabric data to be imported into firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, google-fabric

I have an app with fabric setup for some time now.

And I just recently setup my firebase account for analytics purposes.

From what I understand, since fabric collects some data automatically by itself, I should be able to import those data into firebase.

But after I created a project under firebase, with my app's app id. I don't see anything in either firebase or fabric dashboard such that it allows me to connect one to the other.

What do I need to do? Do I have to setup my actual iOS application with all the google-service.plist stuff and integrate the firebase library and deploy it to production in order for data linking to occur?

Or is there a hidden button somewhere in the dashboard such that I can do it with couple clicks?

Comment: According to a note at the top of the blog post mentioned by Glare Storm (https://fabric.io/blog/fabric-events-to-firebase-integration/),

"Note: We're working on making updates to this feature. It is currently unavailable."

This is probably why you have been having issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the integration covers all this i think 
its listed in the fabric website

from : [here](https://fabric.io/blog/fabric-events-to-firebase-integration/)

The integration only takes a few minutes and can be done by a developer in three simple steps:

```
1.Link apps
2.Upgrade the SDKs
3.Ship your app
```